# How to SUM two SUMmed SQL result fields

Tags: mysql, sql, sum, left-join, where-clause

I have a simple table structure holding records of *reagent_bottles* and *reagent_aliquots*.

Aliquots are created from bottles, and an aliquot record got a foreign key, bottle_id, to a bottles id.

To get the total volume of a particular reagent (counting both the volume in the bottles and the volume in the aliquots), the following query does the job, partly:

```
SELECT  
      COALESCE(SUM(rb.volume), 0) AS bVolume, 
      COALESCE(SUM(ra.volume), 0) AS aVolume
FROM reagent_bottles AS rb
LEFT JOIN 
      reagent_aliquotes AS ra
ON rb.id = ra.bottle_id
WHERE reagent_id = 408;
```

returns for the above reagent id (408):

```
bVolume | aVolume
       2|       6
```

Adding bVolume and aVolume, is the correct answer, i.e. 8.

Question is, how do I re-write the above query to create a new field, **total_volume**, summing bVolume and aVolume within the query?

I tried this:

```
SELECT  
      COALESCE(SUM(rb.volume), 0) AS bVolume , 
      COALESCE(SUM(ra.volume), 0) AS aVolume, 
      SUM(bVolume + aVolume) AS total_volume
FROM 
      reagent_bottles AS rb
LEFT JOIN 
      reagent_aliquotes AS ra
ON rb.id = ra.bottle_id
WHERE reagent_id = 408;
```

but getting the error, *Unknown column, bVolume in field list*..!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sum the original columns:

```
SELECT  
      COALESCE(SUM(rb.volume), 0) AS bVolume , 
      COALESCE(SUM(ra.volume), 0) AS aVolume, 
      SUM(COALESCE(rb.volume, 0) + COALESCE(ra.volume, 0)) AS total_volume
FROM 
      reagent_bottles AS rb
LEFT JOIN 
      reagent_aliquotes AS ra
ON rb.id = ra.bottle_id
WHERE reagent_id = 408;
```

Comment: This raises an interesting point, as to which value the OP wants to COALESCE. `SUM(COALESCE... + COALESCE...)` will yield different results to `COALESCE(SUM...) + COALESCE(SUM...)`

Comment: @e_i_pi I guess I want to coalesce first, as I want to avoid negative volumes (should never exist), and sum the values afterwards.